# regex batch delete

Tags: javascript, regex

how can i change this

```
<center><h2>داستان عیسا مسیح برای کودکان</h2>2. The Story of Jesus for Children</center>
<center><h2>کوکی ها</h2>1. The Jesus Film</center>
<center><h2>مریم مجدلیله</h2>5. Magdelena: Released from Shame</center>
```

to this

```
<center><h2>داستان عیسا مسیح برای کودکان</h2>The Story of Jesus for Children</center>
<center><h2>کوکی ها</h2>The Jesus Film</center>
<center><h2>مریم مجدلیله</h2>Magdelena: Released from Shame</center>
```

Comment: Note that the `center` tag is deprecated.

Comment: @RobW Wasn't hard at all, which is why I said it looked like he already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it

```
source.replace(/(<\/h2>)\d{1}\.\s+/g, '$1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be removing the pattern of "number followed by `.` followed by space". In which case:

```
val = val.replace(/[0-9]+\. /g,"");
```

would work just fine.

Comment: Although I'd add something contextual to avoid removing it from other places, like a preceding `</h2>` element.

Comment: If this answer was satisfactory, please mark it as Accepted. Seriously, I hit the 200 limit for upvotes so I really need people to Accept my answers when they're helpful :p